# Transform row to nested JSON in Spark

Tags: java, json, apache-spark

I am trying to transform a row into a nested JSON structure in Spark.

The rows are loaded from a comma-separated values file:

```
identifier,timestamp,x,y
2,         456,      1,x
1,         456,      1,y
1,         123,      0,x
1,         789,      0,z
```

The rows should be transformed into the following JSON format (grouped by identifier and sorted by timestamp):

```
{"identifier":"1","events":[{"timestamp":"123","properties":{"x":"0","y":"x"}},{"timestamp":"456","properties":{"x":"1","y":"y"}},{"timestamp":"789","properties":{"x":"0","y":"z"}}]}

{"identifier":"2","events":[{"timestamp":"456","properties":{"x":"0","y":"z"}}]}
```

As of now I succeeded to transform the data into...

```
{"identifier":"1","collect_list(named_struct(NamePlaceholder(), timestamp AS `timestamp`, NamePlaceholder(), named_struct(NamePlaceholder(), x AS `x`, NamePlaceholder(), y AS `y`) AS `properties`) AS `events`)":[{"timestamp":"123","properties":{"x":"0","y":"x"}},{"timestamp":"456","properties":{"x":"1","y":"y"}},{"timestamp":"789","properties":{"x":"0","y":"z"}}]}

{"identifier":"2","collect_list(named_struct(NamePlaceholder(), timestamp AS `timestamp`, NamePlaceholder(), named_struct(NamePlaceholder(), x AS `x`, NamePlaceholder(), y AS `y`) AS `properties`) AS `events`)":[{"timestamp":"456","properties":{"x":"0","y":"z"}}]}
```

using the following code:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Column properties = struct(col("x").as("x"), col("y").as("y")).as("properties");
    final Column event = struct(col("timestamp").as("timestamp"), properties).as("events");

    final SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate();
    final Dataset<Row> events = sparkSession.read().option("header", "true").csv("/input/events").sort(col("identifier").asc(), col("timestamp").asc());
    Dataset<String> groupedEvents = events.groupBy("identifier").agg(collect_list(event)).toJSON();
    groupedEvents.write().text("/output/events");
    sparkSession.stop();
}
```

However, this resulting transformation also includes...

```
"collect_list(named_struct(NamePlaceholder(), timestamp AS `timestamp`, NamePlaceholder(), named_struct(NamePlaceholder(), x AS `x`, NamePlaceholder(), y AS `y`) AS `properties`) AS `events`)
```

which I would like to be equal to "events".

How to produce the described transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed myself using the following:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate();
    final Dataset<Row> events = sparkSession.read().option("header", "true").csv("/input/events");
    events.createOrReplaceTempView("groupedevents");
    final Dataset<String> groupedEvents = sparkSession.sql("select identifier, sort_array(collect_list(struct(timestamp, struct(x, y) as properties))) as events from groupedevents group by identifier").toJSON();
    groupedEvents.write().text("/output/events");
    sparkSession.stop();
}
```